# How do you format the date used in the popover widget title of FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar, how do you format the date used in the popover widget title when clicking '+n more'?

Code:

```
<div class="fc-popover fc-more-popover">
    <div class="fc-header fc-widget-header">
        <span class="fc-close fc-icon fc-icon-x"></span>            
        <span class="fc-title">Tuesday, April 7</span>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: you could try `eventRender()` method for changing the appereance.

Comment: Already tried that with no luck. Do you have a specific code snippet that targets what I want to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [dayPopoverFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/dayPopoverFormat/) for that.

> Determines the date format of title of the popover created by the
>   [eventLimitClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimitClick/) option.
>
> Must be a date formatting string. The default value is "dddd, MMMM D" for English and "LL" for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `dayPopoverFormat` property of fullcalender.
For more detail check this. [Fullcalender dayPopoverFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/dayPopoverFormat/)